# Not returning all rows with LEFT JOINS and HAVING

Tags: mysql, group-by, left-join, having

I am building a simple forum. What I need to display is a list with the latest Topics and near each topic it's latest reply/post. Something like:

```
Topic name:         | Last reply:
Topic name 1 here   | 2013-02-01 by username1
Topic name 2 here   | 2013-01-01 by username2
etc.
```

The thing is that Topics and Replies are both in the same table called 'pages'.
This table has a field template which contains of course an ID for the table 'templates'.

So I simply join templates and filter by the Template.name for the record 'Forum topic'

This will return all topics. Because I also needed the latest reply for each topic I decided to do a subquery with a filter on the same template but now for the record 'Forum reply' and ordered by Reply.date DESC and with a LIMIT 1 which returns the latest reply for this topic. Now it is time to show my current query which works fine for Topics that contain at least 1 reply:

```
/*----some fields to return----*/
SELECT TopicContent.title, ReplyContent.title, Reply.date, Reply.id, 
(
  /*----subquery to return latest reply id used inside HAVING later on----*/
  SELECT Reply.id
  FROM pages AS Reply
  INNER JOIN templates AS Template ON Reply.template = Template.id
  WHERE Reply.parent_id = Topic.id
  AND Template.name =  'Forum reply'
  ORDER BY Reply.date DESC 
  LIMIT 1
) AS reply_id
FROM pages AS Topic
INNER JOIN templates AS Template ON Topic.template = Template.id
INNER JOIN page_content AS TopicContent ON Topic.id = TopicContent.page
/*----left join used because topic could have zero replies if new----*/
LEFT JOIN pages AS Reply ON Topic.id = Reply.parent_id
LEFT JOIN page_content AS ReplyContent ON Reply.id = ReplyContent.page
WHERE Template.name =  'Forum topic'
HAVING Reply.id = reply_id
/*--------------------------------------------------------------------------------*/
/*----HAVING            | returns not all topics but with correct latest reply----*/
/*----GROUP BY Topic.id | returns topics correctly but incorrect latest reply-----*/
```

Most important now is that if a new Topic is submitted it does not contain any replies yet.

So when I use HAVING it returns only Topics that also contain at least one reply.
And when using GROUP BY it does not return the latest replies for the topics that contain one or more replies. And for the topics that do not contain replies it returns NULL which is good.

Do I need to change JOINS? Any ideas to resolve this. Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd move the MaxId subquery to the from clause as the way you're using GROUP BY won't work for what you're trying to do. Here you just join your resultset to a subquery that retrieves your MaxId field.

```
SELECT
*
FROM 
   pages
   .
   .
   .
   LEFT OUTER JOIN 
   (
   SELECT 
      ReplyId As [MaxId], 
      p.Template
   FROM 
      Pages p INNER JOIN Templates t ON p.Template = t.Id
   WHERE
      TemplateName = 'Forum Reply'
   ORDER BY ReplyDate LIMIT 1
   ) a ON a.Template = pages.Template
WHERE 
   Template.name =  'Forum topic'
```

Alternatively (this one could give you more than one reply if multiple first replies have the exact same time in which case you could limit the results)

```
SELECT
   *
FROM
   pages
   .
   .
   .
   (SELECT
      ReplyId As [MaxiId],
      Template
   FROM
      Pages p INNER JOIN
      Templates t ON p.Template = t.id LEFT OUTER JOIN
      (SELECT 
         p.Template, 
         MIN(ReplyDate) AS [FirstReplyDate]
      FROM      
         Pages p INNER JOIN
         Templates t ON p.Template = t.id
      WHERE
         TemplateName = 'Forum Reply'
      GROUP BY
         p.Template) b ON b.Template = t.id
   WHERE 
      p.ReplyDate = b.FirstReplyDate
   ) a ON a.Template = pages.Template
```

Either way you should be moving that first reply subquery to the From clause

Comment: Thank you for your answer benglish. Can you explain why you JOIN on a.TemplateId = pages.TemplateId. I tried to figure / work it out but don't seem to work.

Comment: It may be because I don't quite understand your data structure but in your subquery you join the pages table to the templates table on this column (I'll edit it to use the same names you've used). The above should give you a general solution.

Comment: Hello benglish. Thanks for your help. Although it did not work. I think it is not possible to achive this. Not at our ways. That is why I decided to ceperate the Topics and Replies from the pages table. I am now making the tables topics and replies and change my script. This way is of course the best and now I do not have empty fields annymore at my pages table which is also great. Just was wondering if it could be accomplished.

Answer (score 0):

This is not the answer yet, but rather, it is to ask for more information from the poster, but because it is too long for comment, I will post here.

From your query, I can conclude that your tables look something like this

```
templates(id, name)
pages(id, parent_id, date, template)
page_contents(page, title)
```

`pages` stores the structure of the post, `page_contents` stores the content of the post, and `template` determine what type of post. Am I correct?

Question:

- What is the value of parent_id, if it is topic, not a reply. Since reply is under topic, so the `parent_id` should be the ID of the topic. However, topic does not under any topic, so basically, it should be either 0 or NULL, is it right?
- Do you limit yourself to this database design, from my perspective, this database design does not fit for forum because to retrieve something as simple as this, you have to INNER JOIN a bunch of tables.

Comment: You are correct about how my table looks like. The Topic parent_id has a parent page which is in this case 'News and info'. This is a parent page which has a template 'Forum group'. The parent of the forum group is 'Forum'. So the topic parent_id value is never 0. No I am not limited. I made this structure my own because I thought it would be handy when having a multi language website. Wich will be stored in page_content. I am free to do wathever I want so I could make extra tables called 'topics' and 'replies' but I prever not to if possible. Thanks for quick reply for now.